# What is the minimum Artifactory publish configuration?

Tags: java, jenkins, artifactory

My Jenkins build produces a single Java binary `boo.jar`. I want to push `boo.jar` to Artifactory. Any variant of this result will do; I'm sure it will be fine.

The suggestions elsewhere on the internet would suggest I make some Maven, Ivy, or Gradle artifacts that (by an undescribed process) make this happen if you get the incantation right. I have a background in lots of technology, but there's a big hole in my knowledge of the Java toolchain. Ideally, I don't want to spend the time learning which of these artifact configuration methods is right for me, what is the shape it expects things from me, etc.

There must be a way to *push a file to a predictable path* without a large project configuration; that's all I really need.

Does such a way exist? Am I misguided?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is Artifactory Jenkins plugin with [Generic Build Configuration](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Artifactory+Plugin#ArtifactoryPlugin-ConfiguringGeneric%28Freestyle%29Builds).

Comment: I'm actually surprised the answer wasn't "you need to read the Ivy book."

Comment: no, no. If you don't need/want dependency management, just go and specify where you want to put your jar :)
And if we are on it, if you do want one, go with Gradle :)